# Dynamically calculate last filled column multiplied by the average of its previous 3 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the below spreadsheet

```
A   B   C   D   E
    1   2   3   4
```

I use this formula in to calculate A1

```
=AVERAGE(B2:D2)*E2
```

However, I need to make it extensible to the addition of new columns, for example:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
    1   2   3   4   5
```

I would need A1 to calculate

```
=AVERAGE(C2:E2)*F2
```

Which is, the last filled column multiplied by the average of its previous 3 columns.

Comment: instead of putting your formula in A1, put it in A2. then drag/fill the formula accross that riw and the cell references will automatically change. If you insist on having your formula in A1, one alternative is you'll need to figure out the formulas of index/match and offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B2:XFD2,-4+MAX(ISNUMBER(B2:XFD2)*COLUMN(B2:XFD2))):INDEX(B2:XFD2,-2+MAX(ISNUMBER(B2:XFD2)*COLUMN(B2:XFD2))))*INDEX(B2:XFD2,-1+MAX(ISNUMBER(B2:XFD2)*COLUMN(B2:XFD2)))
```

Comment: Some explanations will be usefull.

Comment: @Toto Use the `evaluate function` tool, then ask about what part you don't understand.

Comment: There is nothing I don't understand, but it's always better to explain what your function does in detail, at least for newbie users.

Comment: @Toto I disagree. I think it is better to figure out something for myself. But this is not a topic for comments.